# Azure Functions - only use connection string in Application Settings in cloud for queue trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function in Visual Studio:

```
    [FunctionName("MyQueueProcessor")]
    [StorageAccount("StorageConnectionString")]
    public static async Task ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("my-queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        logInfo("Start processing message", LogLevel.TRACE, message, log);
    }
```

I have StorageConnectionString set in the Application Settings in the cloud, and when I upload the function from Visual Studio to an Azure App, the function initially runs without issues.

The problem is that the function app restarts frequently, and sometimes when it restarts, the function doesn't run. From looking at Application Insights, I get the following error:

> The following 2 functions are in error: ProcessQueueMessage:
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'MyQueueTrigger.ProcessQueueMessage'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK 'StorageConnectionString' connection
>   string is missing or empty. The Microsoft Azure Storage account
>   connection string can be set in the following ways: 1. Set the
>   connection string named 'StorageConnectionString' in the
>   connectionStrings section of the .config file in the following format
>   , or 2. Set the environment variable named
>   'StorageConnectionString', or 3. Set corresponding property of
>   JobHostConfiguration. Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error
>   indexing method 'MyTimerTrigger.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK 'StorageConnectionString' connection
>   string is missing or empty. The Microsoft Azure Storage account
>   connection string can be set in the following ways: 1. Set the
>   connection string named 'StorageConnectionString' in the
>   connectionStrings section of the .config file in the following format
>   , or 2. Set the environment variable named
>   'StorageConnectionString', or 3. Set corresponding property of
>   JobHostConfiguration.

It appears that sometimes when the function app restarts, the binding to StorageConnectionString fails. How can I prevent this from being an issue?

Comment: You can try the two methods. 1. set the `StorageConnectionString` in the `local.settings.json` file and publish the function again 2.set `Always On` in the `Application Settings` in the portal

Comment: Would local.settings.json really work? I thought that file doesn't get uploaded.

Comment: I tried setting "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", and the function stopped working. I'm guessing it's not possible to have this setup on the consumption plan?

Comment: The `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` is for the emulator, you should specify it as your storage connection string.

Comment: And the default timeout for functions on a Consumption plan is 5 minutes, the restart may caused by it, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan).

Comment: I have a timer trigger that adds to the queue every two minutes, so I don’t think it’s related.

Comment: My connection string for production isn’t the emulator. I just don’t want the connection string for production in the code base.