# Azure Functions - Queue trigger consumes message on fail

Tags: azure, azure-functions

This issue only occurs when I use the Azure Portal Editor. If I upload from Visual Studio, this issue does not occur, but I cannot upload from Visual Studio due this unrelated bug: [Azure Functions - only use connection string in Application Settings in cloud for queue trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754119/azure-functions-only-use-connection-string-in-application-settings-in-cloud-fo).

When using the Azure Portal Editor, if I throw an exception from C# or use `context.done(error)` from JavaScript, Application Insights shows an error occurred, but the message is simply consumed. The message is not retried, and it does not go to a poison queue.

The same code for C# correctly retries when uploaded from Visual Studio, so I believe this is a configuration issue. I have tried modifying the host.json file for the Azure Portal Editor version to:

```
{
  "queues": {
        "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:15",
        "maxDequeueCount": 5
    }
}
```

but the message was still getting consumed instead of retried. How do I fix this so that I can get messages to retry when coding with the Azure Portal Editor?

Notes:

In JavaScript, `context.bindingData.dequeueCount` returns `0`.

Azure Function runtime version: `1.0.11913.0 (~1)`.

I'm using a Consumption App Plan.

Comment: Interesting. I'd like to look at this from our side; would you mind sharing the following information? 1) The name of your Function app ([here's how to share privately](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)), 2) The name of your function, and 3) The timeframe within which you observed this.

Comment: Function started (Id=f6ca5d6b-3b63-4696-9be5-0d9d33785dc4) at 2018-07-18T17:01:01.460. Function completed (Failure, Id=f6ca5d6b-3b63-4696-9be5-0d9d33785dc4, Duration=2892ms) at 2018-07-18T17:01:04.350.

Comment: Region is South Central US.

Comment: That's a Function we are only using for testing. There is also a live component affected, so please let me know if I need to send you that function's information too.

Comment: Our logs indicate the function invocation whose information you gave me was manually triggered (probably from the portal), so I have no information about queue behavior. Can you give me the live component's information?

Comment: That is correct. Let me manually add a message to the queue, which sounds like it will have the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Well, that worked. I must have just misunderstood the behavior of the manual trigger. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to post that answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the manual trigger from the Azure Portal Editor, which has different behavior from creating a message in the queue. When I put a message in the queue, the Azure Function worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For local development, if your function is async use `Task` for the return type.

```
public async Task Run
```

instead of `void`:

```
public async void Run
```